# Hex tasks not found in list of mix tasks

Tags: hex, elixir, elixir-mix

I have a very simple project and I am trying to publish the first version to hex. However I cannot run the **hex.publish** task.

> I get the error ** (Mix) The task "hex.publish" could not be found.

I am following these [hex instructions](https://hex.pm/docs/publish).

My `mix.exs` file looks like the following.

```
defmodule Ace.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :ace,
     version: "0.2.0",
     elixir: "~> 1.0",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps]
  end

  def application do
    [
      applications: [:logger],
      mod: {Ace, []}
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
    []
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have `hex` installed? Try running `mix local.hex` and then `mix hex.publish`.

Comment: @Dogbert You should post that as an answer in case anyone else runs across this.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I was waiting for OP to confirm :)

Comment: yep that was what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might not have `hex` installed. According to [hex usage](https://hex.pm/docs/usage), please use

```
mix local.hex
```

in your terminal or CMD console.
Then `mix hex.publish` should work.

Comment: You should mark your answer community wiki since you've basically taken Dogbert's answer.